# Dhumra Ganapati in Dhumavati Sadhana

Tags: mantras, tantra, dasha-mahavidya, ganapati, dhumavati

I am seeking a deeper understanding of Dhumavati Sadhana. In this mahavidya there is Dhumra Ganapati to be worshipped before. I'm seeking more resources about this form of Ganapati and it's mantras.

Can anybody point me in to right direction where one could fine Dhumra Ganapati's mantra (11 syllables with धूं instead of omkara). Also expanding there is apparently a aghora and shabar mantras of this Ganapati.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, guidance, or resources you could provide on this topic. Thank you for your time and assistance.